# Can we access one control Id registered in one aspx in to another ascx control,,

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can we access one control Id registered in one aspx in to another ascx control,,

Comment: I think you need to be a little bit more specific about the relationship between the ASPX and ASCX and what type of control it is (and what "registered" means in this context while we're at it).

Comment: for ex: in index.aspx one sitemap control id is registered
    <asp:SiteMapPath ID="acsSiteMap" runat="server">

        </asp:SiteMapPath>
i need to access  ID 'acsSiteMap' in other usercontrol(ascx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in an ascx and need to access a control in the parent aspx page, you could do this as follows:

```
Control myControl = this.Page.FindControl("myControl");
```

However, it is worth investigating exactly why you need to do this - in general it is not a good practice for the child user control to perform actions inside the parent page. An alternative approach would be to have the ascx throw an event in a given scenario, which the parent Page would in turn subscribe to (and potentially perform an internal action based on the event). This would allow interoperability between the page and User Control while still encapsulating each one's functionality properly.

Comment: thanks for the comments,,we need to generate a recursive function if that contain more than one controls

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I guess you are trying to access a page's control from inside a .ascx control, am I right?

If that is the question, the answer is no, you can't. Or you at least, you shouldn't (as other answers have shown in fact you can do it)

You shouldn't do it because a .ascx control is meant to be reusable. So it must be independent from any page, it must have meaning by itself. For example, can you imagine a textbox control that needs some element with a name in the page where it is used?

If you need the control to access data from the page, you must do it the other way around. The page must feed the data to control via a public property.

Hope that helps

Comment: but 'Control' class in namespace System.Web.UI will defines all properties,methods,events shared by asp.net server controls,,now i googled for this

Comment: Yes, you are right. But, how does that change anything? Maybe I still haven't understood your question?